# Can a group of order 3000 be a simple group?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Can a group of order 3000 be a simple group? How about the case of a group of order 1000?

Comment: No, because neither $1000$ nor $3000$ is prime, and neither is on the [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_simple_groups#Non-cyclic_simple_groups_of_small_order).

Comment: i know that but could you give a concrete proof for that? i.e for a group of order 1000? thanks

Comment: @Bone: do you have any specific difficulty with this problem?

Answer (score 4):

A group of order 1000 has a normal Sylow 5-subgroup, so it cannot be simple.

A group of order 3000 has either a normal Sylow 5-subgroup or 6 of them. If there are 6 Sylow 5-subgroups, then the normalizer of a Sylow 5-subgroup has order 3000/6 = 500. A subgroup of order 500 cannot have a trivial normal core in a group of order 3000: Index of the normal core in the Sylow 5-subgroup must divide (6 - 1)! but 500 does not divide 120 = 5!.

Answer (score 2):

Theorem: Let $G$ be a simple group and $H<G$ such that $[G:H]=n$ then $$G\hookrightarrow A_n$$

Comment: Nice, Babak! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

(1) Let $\,G\,$ be a group, $\,H\le G\,\;,\;\;X:=$ the set of left cosets of $\,H\,$ in $\,G\,$ . The regular action of $\,G\,$ in $\,X\,$ is given by $\,g(g_1H)\mapsto(gg_1)H\,$ and, as any other action of a group on a set, it determines a group homomorphism $\,\phi:G\to \text{Sym}_X:=\,$ the group of all bijections from the set $\,X\,$ to itself. Note that if $\,[G:H]=n\,$ then $\,\text{Sym}_X\cong S_n\,$ .  The kernel of this homomorphism, say $\,N:=\ker\phi\;$ , is the maximal normal subgroup of $\,G\,$ *that is contained in $\,H\,$* .

2) From the above it follows that if a group $\,G\,$ cannot be embedded in some $\,S_n\,$ then $\,|N|>1\,$

3) Thus, a group $\,G\,$ with a subgroup $\,H\le G\,$ s.t. $\,[G:H]=n\,$ and $\,|G|\,\nmid\,n!\,$ cannot be simple

Finally, a group of order $\,3,000=5^3\cdot 3\cdot 3^3\,$ has either one or six Sylow $\,5$-subgroups, yet the second option would there exists a subgroup in $\,G\,$ of *index* $\,6\,$ , and this means $\,G\,$ cannot be simple.

Answer (score -1):

let $G$ be a group of 3000 .Then by SYLOWS theorem $G$ contain a subgroup $H$ of order 1000. as$ 0(G)$ does not devide factorial of $(i(H))$. $H$ contain a non trivial normal subgroup $K$ of $G$ which contain in $H$. so $G$ is not simple. where $i(H)$ means index set of $H$ in $G$

Comment: How does it follow from Sylow theorems that there is a group of order $\,1,000\,$ ?